# Interactive GQL on GAE/J dev server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

On the production servers I can use the datastore viewer to compose some GQL (as long as it's supported by the indexes) and find data on the fly.  What's the best way to do this on the dev server?

I'm using the Java sdk 1.4.3, and I already have remote_api installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ansewr seems to be that there is no way to do this.  I implemented a quick servlet to do arbitrary gql for me, which isn't *too* much work, though it is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

[The Development Console](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver.html#The_Development_Console) is accessable at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin

Comment: Thanks for the answer - how can I execute queries with it?